# How to check the name of a Power Point 2010 object manually?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I check the name of a power point object ? I know how to do this using VBA

```
Name$ = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
 MsgBox Name$
```

But i cant find how I could check the name of a shape manually in Power Point 2010 .

There must be a manual way . Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Ribbon "Format" tab, select the "Selection Pane" toggle button.

Changing the selected object will change the highlighted item in the list of shapes on the slide.